# Im trying to test out node.js

Tags: node.js, macos

so I just downloaded and installed node/npm and attempted to run a test with the following code.

```
const http = require(‘http’);

const hostname = ‘127.0.0.1’;
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
res.statusCode = 200;
res.setHeader(‘Content-Type’, ‘text/plain’);
res.end(‘Hello from NodeJS\n’);
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

but the output gives me plenty of error messages (an identifier cant go after this identifier, this cant go here, unexpected, etc) I see a couple of things that could be wrong, but I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using some strange characters, this: ’

Try to use " or ' in module import, setHeader, ...

Answer (score 0):

I would direct you to https://nodejs.dev/learn

You need to require the http module by doing `const http = require('http');`

Also your quotation marks are improper they must be single quotes, double quotes, or backticks. They cannot be whatever unicode character you have in there.